# 2009 Corsa D 1.4 rattling engine part

Tags: noise, vauxhall, corsa

My girlfriend's Corsa is making a slightly strange ticking/rattling noise. I've found the cause to be these plastic parts (actuators for something?) and the metal clips that are retaining them. (behind the injector plugs; round metal clips)

[image: plastic parts]

You can't see the parts too well in the zoomed out pic but they seem to be in line with the four cylinders.

[image: More zoomed out pic here].

When I put pressure on the parts with my finger while the engine is idling, the noise greatly reduces.

Is this normal as the engines get older? Is there any way of reducing the rattle?
As an aside, what are these parts called/for?

Comment: Those parts are the plugs for the fuel injectors. Try to remove and re-insert the plug. Are all plugs affected?

Comment: Thank you but it's not the plugs, it's the parts behind them, with the round silver clips. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Those are some kind of securing rings for the intake manifold. Perhaps you can fix them by gently pushing and turning them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disassembling the motor for other reasons, I have discovered that this part is part of the swirl flap actuator assembly.

Replacing the clips and fixing the new ones tightly reduced the noise by around 50%.